# Error trying to download file using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, mechanize, urllib

I have been trying to download a link to automate the stock market and my code runs but the zip file does not get downloaded.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import requests

url ='https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2016/DEC/cm29DEC2016bhav.csv.zip'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
print "downloading with urllib"
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "code.zip")

print "downloading with urllib2"
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = f.read()
with open("code2.zip", "wb") as code:
    code.write(data)

print "downloading with requests"
r = requests.get(url)
with open("code3.zip", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

I would like the zip file to be downloaded in the C:\Users\User\Downloads folder so that I can automate the unzip process and then save that csv file into the hard disk. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The file is getting download to the Current Working Directory, maybe `C:\Python[Version]`. Go check there. Try this to download it to `Downloads` folder:

```
import requests

url ='https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2016/DEC/cm29DEC2016bhav.csv.zip'
print "downloading with requests"
r = requests.get(url)
with open("C:\Users\User\Downloads\code3.zip", "w") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Nope give the error that no such file or directory as code3.zip. But appreciate the help

Comment: @arnav Can you try again. I removed the `b` flag. Also can you include the full error traceback in the question? I'm on linux so I can't test it but I'm trying to make an accurate guess.

Comment: I just tried a different answer and it worked. I think I was just trying to find it in the Downloads folder but it was getting downloaded in the working directory. Lol that was stupid :P